# List index out of range error, for list containing string

Tags: python, list, indexing, binary

I have a list of lists called headers.The data contained in each of these sub lists are binary.

headers[5] = ['t\x04\x1e\x01I\x1a\t\x11\x02Rz\x7fI\x00H:\x00\x1a\x13I\x1aOEH\x0f\x1d\rS\x04']

When ,I have a list such as l = ["hello",1,22,"ex"], I can use l[0][2] to access the element 'l'.

Similarly, when I want to access the n'th byte of the binary data contained in list headers[5], I get a list index out of range error. How can I access the n'th byte in this list headers[5] ?

My objective is to create a list of lists from the given binary data in the file object 'text',by splitting the file into 'keysize' length bytes.

After that, I want to place the first byte of all the lists into a new list in the list 'nheads', second byte of all the lists of 'heads' into nheads and so on .

Part of my code is:

```
parti = len(text)/keysize 
headers = [[] for k in range(0, parti)]
nheads = [[] for k in range(0, parti)]
pcount = 0
for i in xrange(0,parti):
    if (pcount < len(text)):
        headers[i].append(text[i*keysize:(i+1)*keysize])
        pcount += 1
    else :
        pcount += 1

print headers[5][2]
count = 0
for i in xrange(0,parti):
    for j in xrange(0,parti):
        if(count < len(text)):
            nheads[i].append(headers[j][i])
            count = count + 1
        else:
            count = count + 1
```

The error i get is :

```
utkarsh@utkarsh-Lenovo-G580:~/crypto$ python 6.py 
['t\x04\x1e\x01I\x1a\t\x11\x02Rz\x7fI\x00H:\x00\x1a\x13I\x1aOEH\x0f\x1d\rS\x04']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "6.py", line 65, in <module>
nheads[i].append(headers[j][i])
IndexError: list index out of range
utkarsh@utkarsh-Lenovo-G580:~/crypto$ python 6.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "6.py", line 60, in <module>
print headers[5][2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please post an example of the code you are running, the actual traceback you get from running that code, and the expected output.

Comment: If `heads[5]` is returning a single item list, are you currently trying `heads[5][char_index]` when what you want is `heads[5][0][char_index]`?

Comment: I tried that too , i get the error string index out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibility:
1. The head list is not initialized properly so the length of it is smaller than 6.
2. The n is bigger than length of head[5].
Try print(str(head[5])). If error occurred, case 1 otherwise case 2.
Also try len(head) and len(head[5]) in order.

Answer (score 0):

Since the list is a list of lists, the second element selector you are using is selecting the element within the contained list, not the byte element within the binary string.

Try "heads[5][0][n]" instead of "heads[5][n]".